# How to clear ultraComboEditor in 4GL/ABL

Tags: combobox, progress-4gl

I have a ultraComboEditor1 box that shows all the values linked to a data source. When I select item from the comboEditor and click on a button this item then appears in a grid. However I'm struggling to clear the item from the comboEditor. This is needed so it makes data entry easier for the user.

I have looked online and the only information I can find is for C# where this would be used:

ultraComboEditor1.RowSource = "".

```
    or
```

ultraComboEditor1.item.Clear().

```
    or
```

ultraComboEditor1.SelectedIndex = -1.

these all work but in 4GL when trying any of these I get eh error message "Unknown Table name UltraComboEditor1" as only tables can be followed by a .

can anyone help me figure out how to do this in 4GL or provide with some information that may help?

Thank

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used: `ultraComboEditor1:text = "".` to clear the combo Editor on the button click event.

Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use ":" instead of "." to translate your c# examples into 4GL -

```
ultraComboEditor:Item:Clear()
```

etc